# Get non-duplicate rows from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a numpy array of the form

```
x = np.array([[2, 5],
              [3, 4],
              [1, 3],
              [2, 5],
              [4, 5],
              [1, 3],
              [1, 4],
              [3, 4]])
```

What I would like to get from this is an array which contains only the rows which are NOT duplicates, i.e., I expect from this example

```
array([[4, 5],
       [1, 4]])
```

I'm looking for a method which is reasonably fast and scales well. The only way that I can think to do this is

1. First find the set of unique rows in `x`, as a new array `y`.
2. Create a new array `z` which has those individual elements of `y` removed from `x`, thus `z` is a list of the duplicated rows in `x`.
3. Do a set difference between `x` and `z`.

This seems horribly inefficient though. Anyone have a better way?

*If it is important, I'm guaranteed that each of my rows will be sorted smallest to largest so that you'll never have a row be `[5, 2]` or `[3, 1]`.*

Comment: Why do you think this is inefficient? With a hash table this should be a O(n) time algorithm which is pretty reasonable. You can not do much better since you have to look at each element.

Comment: I expect it to be inefficient due to having to perform the loops myself. I know of no native numpy method that will perform step 2.

Comment: Oh, I see, but I don't think either numpy or pandas optimized these with C code, you might also want to compare the running time with your own loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's an approach based on [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and considering each row as an indexing tuple for efficiency (assuming that the input array has integers) -

```
# Consider each row as indexing tuple & get linear indexing value             
lid = np.ravel_multi_index(x.T,x.max(0)+1)

# Get counts and unique indices
_,idx,count = np.unique(lid,return_index=True,return_counts=True)

# See which counts are exactly 1 and select the corresponding unique indices 
# and thus the correspnding rows from input as the final output
out = x[idx[count==1]]
```

**Note:** If there is a huge number of columns in the input array, you might want to get the linear indices `lid` manually, for which you can use [`np.cumprod`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html), like so -

```
lid = x.dot(np.append(1,(x.max(0)+1)[::-1][:-1].cumprod())[::-1])
```

**Approach #2**

Here's an alternative one that offloads the counting task to [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html), which might be more efficient for such purposes -

```
# Consider each row as indexing tuple & get linear indexing value             
lid = np.ravel_multi_index(x.T,x.max(0)+1)

# Get unique indices and tagged indices for all elements
_,unq_idx,tag_idx = np.unique(lid,return_index=True,return_inverse=True)

# Use the tagged indices to count and look for count==1 and repeat like before
out = x[unq_idx[np.bincount(tag_idx)==1]]
```

**Approach #3**

Here's a different approach using [`convolution`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) to catch such a pattern. Let the inlined comments help out to understand the underlying idea. Here goes -

```
# Consider each row as indexing tuple & get linear indexing value             
lid = np.ravel_multi_index(x.T,x.max(0)+1)

# Store sorted indices for lid
sidx = lid.argsort()

# Append 1s at either ends of sorted and differentiated version of lid
mask = np.hstack((True,np.diff(lid[sidx])!=0,True))

# Perform convolution on it. Thus non duplicate elements would have
# consecutive two True elements, which could be caught with convolution
# kernel of [1,1]. Get the corresponding mask. 
# Index into sorted indices with it for final output
out = x[sidx[(np.convolve(mask,[1,1])>1)[1:-1]]]
```

Comment: I like these methods. I'm actually finding that the first method you've got is faster than the second. Great work though!

Comment: @zephyr Ah I see. Think the performance difference between these two approaches depend on the input array format!

Comment: @zephyr Could you check out the just added third approach for testing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `pandas` approach:

```
pd.DataFrame(x.T).T.drop_duplicates(keep=False).as_matrix()

#array([[4, 5],
#       [1, 4]])
```

Comment: Is the `keep=False` necessary? I get an unexpected keyword error .

Comment: Sometimes it can be so easy. I wished I'd thought of that 20 minutes ago :-(

Comment: be sure to update your pandas version! Otherwise, for former version, with a two liner you can use a mask `df.duplicated() | df.duplicated(take_last=True)` to remove all duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility (requiring a lot of memory for arrays containing a lot of elements) is by first creating a boolean mask where the rows are equal:

```
b = np.sum(x[:, None, :] == x, axis=2)
b
array([[2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]])
```

This array shows which row has how many equal elements with another row. The diagonal is comparing the row with itself so needs to be set to zero:

```
np.fill_diagonal(b, 0)
b
array([[0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Now let's see what is the maximum for each row:

```
c = np.max(b, axis=0)
c
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])
```

and then we need to find the values where this maximum is `!=2` and index these from the original array:

```
x[np.where([c != 2])[1]]
array([[4, 5],
       [1, 4]])
```

Comment: I like that this keeps everything in numpy. Can you tell me how the construct `x[:, None, :]` works? I've never seen that before.

Comment: It adds another dimension. So the result is 3d with an empty axis as second axis and the original second axis as third. Alternativ you yan use `np.expand_dims(x, axis=1)` which is a bit more intuitive but more to write :-)

Answer (score 1):

For completness, see also item 78 in http://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/teaching/numpy.100/

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved efficiently using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
x[npi.multiplicity(x) == 1]
```

Not only is this solution very readable, it is also very efficient, and works with any number of columns or dtypes.